# Difficulty creating Jquery loop to repeatedly change background color and animate element

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, loops

I have been given a task:
"Create a jQuery function which contains a chained effect to slide all the
elements of your page around repeatedly whilst changing the background."

NO PROBLEM:

1:I have created the slide effect repeatedly with setInterval.

PROBLEM:

1.I cant get the jQuery animate effect to work moving the boxes.

```
$(".boxes").animate({right: '500px'}, 1000).animate({left: '500px'}, 1000);
```

2.I cant get the jQuery to change the background repeatedly into different colours.

```
function changecolors() {
        var colors = ["blue", "red", "green", "pink"];
        var counter = 0;
        if (counter < colors.length) {
            $("body").css("background-color", colors[counter], 1000);
            console.log("Counter: " + counter + " Colors Length: " + colors.length + " Colors: " + colors);
            counter++;
        } else {
            counter = 0;
        }
```

3.My counter doesn't work and doesn't want to increase.

Here is a example link:
https://jsfiddle.net/TheWatchman/fb0mt78d/64/

Comment: Your boxes are not positioned, so properties like `right`and `left` _must_ have no effect. Add a little something-something like `.boxes { position: relative; }`, and check what happens then …

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Move `var counter = 0;` outside of `function changecolors()`. Right now each time you call `changecolors()` you set it back to 0.

Comment: Ofcourse, what a simple issue. I feel stupid for even asking now.

Answer (score 0):

`var counter = 0;` must be defined outside the function.

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  setInterval(animateBoxes, 4000);
  setInterval(changecolors, 4000);

  function animateBoxes() {

    $(".boxes").animate({right: '500px'}, 1000).animate({left: '500px'}, 1000);
    $(".boxes").slideUp(2000).slideDown(2000);
  }
  animateBoxes();
var counter = 0;
function changecolors() {
  var colors = ["blue", "red", "green", "pink"];
  
  if (counter < colors.length) {
   $("body").css("background-color", colors[counter], 1000);
   console.log("Counter: " + counter + " Colors Length: " + colors.length + " Colors: " + colors);
   counter++;
  } else {
   counter = 0;
  }

  console.log(colors.length);

 }
 changecolors();


});
```

```css
.box1 {
  width: 120px;
  height: 120px;
  background-color: black;
  color: white;
  text-align:center;
  padding-left
}

.box1 h1{
  padding: 50% 0 50% 0;
}

.box2 {
  width: 180px;
  height: 180px;
  background-color: green;
  text-align:center;
}

.box2 h1{
  padding: 50% 0 50% 0;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>

<html>

  <head>

    <!--Including jQuery -->

    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.4/jquery.min.js">


    </script>
    <link rel='stylesheet' type='text/css' href='stylesheet.css' />
    <script type='text/javascript' src="script.js"></script>
    <!-- Including the scripting file -->
  </head>

  <body>
  
  
  
  <div class="boxes">
  
  
    <div class="box1">
      <h1>
        BOX 1
      </h1>
    </div>

    <div class="box2">
      <h1>
        BOX 2
      </h1>
    </div>
    </div>
   
  </body>

</html>
```

Comment: Thank you so much. That did the trick. Such a simple issue. Feel stupid for even asking now. It worked!